# After submit, dropdown list is empty. Form doesn't work the second session

Tags: python, django

I made a modelform that link to a column in my model. Everything run smooth after I submit the form. However my Stocks dropdown(choicefield) is empty when I want to add more the second time. Is it related to the way I render? or perhaps an html problem?

[image: stock1]

[image: stock2]

forms:

```
class My_Folio(forms.ModelForm):
    symbol = forms.ChoiceField(choices=coin_choices)
    class Meta:
        model = my_data
        widgets = {'event_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'})}
        fields = ['symbol','buy_price','quantity','event_date']
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def blockfolio(request):
    my_coin = my_data.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('symbol')
    if request.method == 'POST':
    my_folio = My_Folio(request.POST)
    if my_folio.is_valid():
            instance = my_folio.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.symbol = my_folio.cleaned_data['symbol']
            instance.save()
            return render(request,'blockfolio/blockfolio.html', {'my_coin':my_coin})
        else: 
            messages.error(request, "Error")
    else:
        my_folio = My_Folio()
    return render( request, 'blockfolio/blockfolio.html', {'my_folio':my_folio})
```

model.py

```
class my_data(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length = 20) 
    buy_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits =30, decimal_places = 10)
    quantity= models.DecimalField(max_digits =30, decimal_places = 10)
    total_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits =30, decimal_places = 10)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    event_date = models.DateField(blank =False, default=datetime.date.today)
```

Template: I think my template could be the problem here, so it's a Modal and also a table. After fill out the stuff in modal, it once submit, it will put that data in table form. But when I click on the modal to add in second entry, I'm not seeing my dropdown values for Stock.

```
 {% extends "blog/base.html"  %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <!-- Modal content-->
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Trade</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form  width="600px"  action="." method="post" oninput="total_value.value= quantity.value *  buy_price.value" >{% csrf_token %}


                                            <div class="row align-items-start">   
                                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                            <label for="symbol">Stocks</label>
                                                            <select class="form-control" id="symbol" name ="symbol">
                                                                    {% for key,choice in my_folio.symbol.field.choices %}
                                                                    <option  >{{key}}</option>     
                                                                    {% endfor%}
                                                            </select>
                                                            {{ my_folio.errors }}
                                                            {{ my_folio.non_field_errors }}
                                                    </div>           

                                                    <div class="form-group">   
                                                            <label for="quantity">Enter your value</label>        
                                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity">

                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                                    <label name ="event_date" id="event_date" for="event_date">Enter your value</label>
                                                            {{my_folio.event_date}}
                                                    </div> 


                                                    <div class="form-group">   
                                                            <label for="buy_price">buy price</label>        
                                                            <input type="number" class="form-control valid" name="buy_price" maxlength="20" id ="buy_price">

                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">   
                                                            <label for="total_value">Total</label>        
                                                            =<output type = "number" name="instance.total_value" id= "total_value" for ="quantity buy_price"></output>

                                                    </div>                        


                                            </div>       

                                            <button type="submit">Submit</button>

                            </form>
                          </div>      
                          <div class="modal-footer">

                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>                        

    </div>   
    <div class="cointainer">
                    <table class = "table">

                       <tr class = " d-none d-sm-table-row">
                         <th colspan="2">ASSET</th>
                         <th class="text-right"> Quantity </th>
                         <th class="text-right"> Buy Price </th>
                         <th class="text-right"> Investment </th>
                         <th class="text-right"> Date </th>
                       </tr>

                      <tbody>
                            {% for item in my_coin %}  
                        <tr class="d-none d-sm-table-row">
                          <td colspan="2"> {{item.symbol}}</td>
                          <td class="text-right"> {{item.quantity}}</td>
                          <td class="text-right"> {{item.buy_price}}</td>
                          <td class="text-right"> {{item.total_value}}</td>
                          <td class="text-right"> {{item.event_date}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="3">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Trade</button>
                          </td>

                        </tr>
                      </tbody> 
                    </table>
                 </div>


    {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I would assume it's something with the view. Can you provide the content of the corresponding view, and probably model too?

Comment: updated my view and model

Comment: I am not sure what you're doing with the `{'my_coin':my_coin}` in the `render` after saving your data. What happens if you replace it with `{'my_folio':instance}` instead?

Comment: yes nothing wrong changing.. but that's the output render. `Instance.save` just save data to `my_coin` so they're the same, but I'm having problem with my form input. Why did the dropdown list become blank?

Comment: I would assume the input goes blank because you're not including the choicefield in the model, only in the form. If you remove the `symbol` line completely from the form, and add choices to the model instead I believe it could work: `symbol = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=coin_choices)`

Comment: tried it, and makemigrations again too. Unfortunately still the same. Thanks for your help tho. Much appreciated it.

Comment: Can you post your template?

Comment: updated my template. I think it's most likely my template because i just throw in from getboostrap the modal and table. Perhaps the `id` or `name` connection is wrong. Maybe modal is mess up.

Comment: I think the problem is that on the post return you are not defining {'my_folio':my_folio} as you do on the other return. You need to supply the template with my_folio on both returns so that the form is rendered properly.
As you can see, on the second screenshot it is not rendering the date input either.